# WebView performs slowly when it is attached to WindowManager android

Tags: android, webview

I'm creating an app shows HTML5 video, for studying android programming, that uses Floating `WebView`.

It performs very choppy even on device that has upgraded `WebView`.
(I'm using lollipop-powered Nexus 5)

While it is attached on Activity(not floating) it performs buttery smooth.
Even if it is floating, it performs smoothly when any `WebView` is placed on Current Activity.
But if there's no `WebView`s on current activity like launcher, it performs very slow and jittery.

Here is part of code what I'm using:

```
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WebView = new WebView();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsRL = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            800,
            450,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    paramsRL.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.loadUrl("html5_video_page_URL_here");
    windowManager.addView(webView,paramsRL);
```

Is there any workaround to get around this problem?

**EDIT**
Added a video explains this behavior: http://youtu.be/BPDxzRRO1N8
while attached to an activity, it performs buttery smooth: http://youtu.be/aQcJRPCZWYs
on Kitkat, at least Samsung Galaxy's, it behaves buttery smooth: http://youtu.be/7Dw0tJ67eJw

I've also filed a bug at
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=460440

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

Hope help you

Comment: You can read more info in here http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: My comment is just to keep your answer on SO, not really to understand it. By rules, answers must be self contained and too short answers are subject to moderation and are usually deleted. That is why I was asking you to elaborate instead of voting for deletion.

Comment: Oy. Sorry about it. I has this issue and i solved it. This code help speed up hảdware and help webview good. Sorry about my English. Regards

Comment: It will be helpful for the community as well as the one who asked the question if you elaborate the explanation and add it to your answer, as well as the link.

Answer (score -1):

I've been working on a application with a floating video player and I had the same issue. I didn't find the root cause of the problem but I got rid of this issue.

I have an activity that starts the Floating Video Player (basically a service that uses the TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT type), when I added a notification player started by the Activity as well (similar to the one used by Spotify), the issue disappeared.

As I said I wasn't able to determine the root cause of the issue, but it seems that as long as the activity or something started by the activity is "active" (I'm using the term active loosely), the issue will no happen and the Webview will behave as expected.